# PaintCode - update view and pass variables

Tags: ios, swift, variables, animation, uiview

Does anyone know of a comprehensive tutorial on implementation of PaintCode, using variables with it, and getting the view to update. I am struggling my way through it. I have built a custom class, and linked a view controller, with a UIView, and I can see the simple graph I made. I have linked it up so that it is @IBDesignable & @IBInspectable and both work fine. I am just not sure how to pass a variable through to the UIView. 
I also have absolutely no idea how to get the thing to update when the variable changes.
Any assistance in this would be great, it has taken all day so far and I feel nowhere closer to solving the issue.

I do appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you share the project, I'll be glad to take a look. I have a working example here, where the variable 'highlighted' is passed in as parameter to the custom view generated in PaintCode: https://github.com/Conaaando/paint-code-ui-button. Key thing there is to call 'setNeedsDisplay' in the custom view.

Answer (score 2):

There a many tutorials in [PaintCode home page](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/tutorials) and at this [other website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/?s=paintcode&cof=FORID%3A10), good lucky

However to access the values you create you just need to create an outlet from the UIView to your UIViewController class and class myViewName.myVariableName = myValue

As [this step by step tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92972/paintcode-tutorial-for-developers-getting-started) explain

Comment: Thank you. I am doing great with Paintcode, but struggling to implement it in a way that is dynamic. I will take a look at the tutorials on Ray Wenderlich's site.

Answer (score 1):

The only tutorials I've found are the [PaintCode website](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/tutorials).

There are three things that I tend to adjust when trying to add/remove parameters to make my drawings more customizable via code.

1. When you click on a canvas, there is a drop down menu in the inspector that allows you to include a draw method, an image method, or both when you export the style kit.
2. When selecting the color in the color palette, there is a drop down menu in the upper right that allows you to make the color a parameter, so that when you export, you can set the color via code.
3. Add a frame to the canvas and set the constraints in the inspector.  These constraints are the old style layout constraints that are very annoying, but doing this inserts a rect parameter in the exported methods which you can set in the code as well.

Comment: Cheers Josh I am struggling with the Xcode end, somewhat. I can get a graphic in, and display it, but I can't do anything with it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any other good PaintCode tutorials - over and above - the tutorials suggested.  But after some research, I think I know the answer to your problem:

Background before the answer: I had the same problem.  For example, you have a good sized image (created by PaintCode) that works on all iPhone device except the iPhone 4S.

To solve my issue:

1. Open PaintCode & find the “Frame” button.
2. Learn a new word “Parametric”.  That is what we are dealing with.  When the frame changes in size, you set whether the objects inside the frame change size or stay the same.
3. Watch the *Dynamic Shapes* tutorial on the [PaintCode site](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/tutorials).  All of the answers are within this short youTube video. It took 5 times of watching it until I have extracted all of the information I needed to get it to work.

If you want the more details, keep reading:

```
@IBDesignable
class beerViewClass: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        SecurityStyleKit.drawCarDashboard(frame: self.bounds, wageIncome: "yo!")
    }
}
```

Notice I can set the frame size as I have multiple views of the same image.  Also I can send in variables to the drawCarDashboard.

- Within PaintCode, put the objects you want to scale / shrink inside the frame.
- Set the Springs and Struts for each item in the frame. For example, do you want it to shrink, stay vertically centered, etc.
- Export your StyleKit to Xcode.
- in Xcode, using Storyboard or code, add the UIViews to your View
  Controller
- Add a new Swift file.
- Change the blank Swift file to a subclass of UIView & add code (see example)
- In storyboard view, select the views that were added.
- Set the view to the class you wrote (beerView)

I hope that helps.  I hope my explanation was clear.